# How one can streamline data to sftp in spring batch writer

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I have following issue to implement as spring batch application.

1. Query external endpoint for data
2. Apply business logic (mapping)
3. Write to csv file
4. Upload those file to sftp server

I expected significant amount of read data. It's not possible to keep all of it in the memory. My question is can and how I can merge step 3 and 4 into one. And the most importantly how one can streamline data directly to sftp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SFTP Outbound Channel Adapter supports payload as an `InputStream`. So, you an transfer data over that stream: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound.

You can use `RemoteFileTemplate` or `SftpSession` directly, though in the Spring Batch `ItemWriter`.

Comment: Yes, I did and it works great. But now I'd like to move file from temporary folder on sftp to destination directory after uploading process is done. But as I recon, RemoteFileTemplate is lacking such a functionality. Probably, I am suppose to use IntegrationFlow ? Is there easy way of doing so ?

Comment: Why is that? There is a `rename(String fromPath, String toPath)` contract. Can't it really rename your remote tmp dir to the actual one?

Comment: I will try that one. Thanks. Naming might have confused me :/